# Grouping List of Lists according to the similar first item

Tags: java, android

I want to group a List of Lists according to the first element in inner lists. The first item in inner list contains some string and I want to group the inner lists with same string in first element.

```
List<String> innerList1= ....
List<String> innerList2= ....
List<String> innerList3= ....

List<List<String>> outerList=....
```

Elements in inner list are like ["US", 999], ["UK", 200], ["US", 456], ["Uk", 800]

So i would like to group these lists according to first element and create seperate (List of Lists) for this.

Comment: Your input is : `["US", 999], ["UK", 200], ["US", 456], ["Uk", 800]` what is your expected output??

Comment: @VishwaRatna My output should be like ["US", 999], ["US", 456],  ["UK", 200], ["Uk", 800], but the data is dynamic means there can be anything in place of US or UK

Comment: Can you clarify are you `List<String>` for the inner list? Because of your input, I think you have using Hashmap. If not, please add code snippet for adding elements like your input.